# Various Country Statistics

Tags: data-request, global, wikipedia

In Wikipedia articles of countries a lot of statistics are given about the country at hand. For example in the [Venezuela article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuela), demographics are described in terms of ethnic groups (e.g. 51.6% are Mestizo), religion (71% catholic), and total population size and population density. There is GDP statistics, Gini-index, Human Development Index, and more.

**Is there any openly available dataset with this type of data for many/all countries?**

I'm of course aware that there is going to be some missing data within such a dataset.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't describe what Wikipedia does, tell us what data you want, specifically; *this type of data* is not enough. ([Read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) for tips)

Comment: BTW You can search the site for all [data-requests for countries](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+country+%5Bdata-request%5D), maybe some of the things you want were already asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[World Statistics](http://world-statistics.org/#indicators) provides the following links:

- [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/)
- [UN](http://data.un.org/)
- [ILO](http://www.ilo.org/global/statistics-and-databases/lang--en/index.htm)
- [FAO](http://www.fao.org/statistics/en/)
- [UNICEF](https://data.unicef.org/)

---

**Software/services**

- [Gapminder](http://www.gapminder.org/)
- [Google Public Data](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_)

**Other sources**

[The World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/).

> The World Factbook is in the public domain and may be used freely by
>   anyone at anytime without seeking permission. However, US Code
>   (Section 403m) prohibits use of the CIA seal in a manner which implies
>   that the CIA approved, endorsed, or authorized such use.

[National Master](http://www.nationmaster.com)

> You may not use any robot, spider or any automated or manual device to
>   monitor or copy any aspect of this site (including content) without
>   the NationMaster prior permission, unless your purpose is to index the
>   content for a traditional search engine (eg. Google, Bink, etc). You
>   may not replicate, modify, reproduce, publish, distribute, display or
>   transmit any portion of this web site, except as permitted in this
>   document.

Answer (score 1):

If the information is already available on Wikipedia then it may be part of http://wiki.dbpedia.org.

For Europe you could use https://www.europeandataportal.eu