# NHANES-like citizen-health dataset but for other countries (EU)

Tags: medical, europe

In the USA, the NHANES datasets are collected by the Center for Disease Control (CDC, the national public health institute in the United States). It represents a random sample of US residents.

Conveniently in R these are already available in the `NHANES` package, containing 2009/2010 data. (I have recommended this in previous answers here).

In NHANES, there are 10000 rows and 76 columns: `ID, SurveyYr, Gender, Age, AgeDecade, AgeMonths, Race1, Race3, Education, MaritalStatus, HHIncome, HHIncomeMid, Poverty,  HomeRooms,  HomeOwn,  Work,  Weight,  Length,  HeadCirc,  Height,  BMI,  BMICatUnder20yrs,  BMI_WHO,  Pulse,  BPSysAve,  BPDiaAve,  BPSys1,  BPDia1,  BPSys2,  BPDia2,  BPSys3,  BPDia3,  Testosterone,  DirectChol,  TotChol,  UrineVol1,  UrineFlow1,  UrineVol2,  UrineFlow2,  Diabetes,  DiabetesAge,  HealthGen,  DaysPhysHlthBad,  DaysMentHlthBad,  LittleInterest,  Depressed,  nPregnancies,  nBabies,  Age1stBaby,  SleepHrsNight,  SleepTrouble,  PhysActive,  PhysActiveDays,  TVHrsDay,  CompHrsDay,  TVHrsDayChild,  CompHrsDayChild,  Alcohol12PlusYr,  AlcoholDay,  AlcoholYear,  SmokeNow,  Smoke100,  Smoke100n,  SmokeAge,  Marijuana,  AgeFirstMarij,  RegularMarij,  AgeRegMarij,  HardDrugs,  SexEver,  SexAge,  SexNumPartnLife,  SexNumPartYear,  SameSex,  SexOrientation,  PregnantNow`

As you can see many questions are quite specific (UrineVol1) and personal (SexNumPartnLife).

Are there any datasets comparable to this,? Similar column-definitions, similar survey method, but for other countries? I am mainly interested in EU countries. Like a GapMinder dataset but for health data, and on an individual level.

(Note to self: check answers to Q [Various country Statistics Q](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11510/various-country-statistics/11511)